# How to pass parameter (id) to message inspector in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, service

I Just want to bound WCF incoming and outgoing messages with some id, what will be logged to database.

As it planned to be used in high multi threaded environment, there is some issues occurred.

---

POST EDIT

Here is how I want to log:

```
public class LogMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> logParams = (Dictionary<string, object>)correlationState;
            logParams["description"] = reply.ToString();

            Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            log.InfoEx(String.Format("response_{0}", logParams["_action"]), logParams);
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {            
            string iteration_id = "";
// here comes seeking for custom, previously setted header with id
            for (int i = 0; i < request.Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                if ((request.Headers[i].Name == "_IterationId") && (request.Headers[i].Namespace == "http://tempuri2.org"))
                {
                    iteration_id = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>(i);
                    request.Headers.RemoveAt(i);

                    break;
                }
            }

            string pair_id = StringGenerator.RandomString(10);
            string action_name = request.Headers.Action.Substring(request.Headers.Action.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            Dictionary<string, object> logParams = new Dictionary<string,object>() { {"iteration_id", iteration_id}, { "description", request.ToString() }, { "request_response_pair", pair_id }, { "_action", action_name } };

            Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            log.InfoEx(String.Format("request_{0}", action_name), logParams);            

            return logParams;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @SonerGönül In fact, I even didn't know how to start solving that issue :)

Comment: Every WCF call has unique id associated with it:OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.MessageId

Comment: @Alexander I want to define own custom ID, associated with other entities in DB.

Comment: Can you at least post service interface and how you plan to generate that ID?

Comment: Have you checked out this article? It is step-by-step how to set up message inspectors on both client and service: http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/29/wcf-message-headers-with-operationcontext-and-with-messageinspector-and-custom-service-behavior/

Comment: @user1467261 I know how to setup message inspectors. The issue is to pass some id (to mark any request and response before logging) to that inspectors from outside world.

Comment: We generate a GUID in AfterReceiveRequest, that is a global variable in IDispatchMessageInspector, BeforeSendReply has access to the variable and write to the db.

Answer (score 10):

If I understood correctly, you want to use an ID as `correlationState` to link the request with the reply.  To do this, return your ID as an object from `BeforeSendRequest`, and it will be passed as an argument to `AfterReceiveReply`.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    var correlationState = ... // for example, a new GUID, or in your case 
                               // an id extracted from the message

    ... do your stuff here

    return correlationState;
}

public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    // the correlationState parameter will contain the value you returned from
    // BeforeSendRequests
}
```

**UPDATE**

> The issue is how to pass parameter to BeforeSendRequest method.

In that case, if you don't have all the information you need already in your request message, the obvious solution is to us a [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) field to communicate information from your caller to `BeforeSendRequest`.

Set the field before calling your service, then extract and use the value in `BeforeSendRequest`.

**UPDATE 2**

> Another option I can use is to set parameter to message itself, but how can I access it in request parameter in BeforeSendRequest?

I don't understand this question.  If I understood right, you want to be able to pass a parameter from the caller to the `BeforeSendRequest` method.  You know how to pass it from `BeforeSendRequest` to `AfterReceiveReply`, using correlationState.

The way to do this is to use a `ThreadStatic` field.  For example, you could create the following class:

```
public static class CallerContext
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static object _state;

    public static object State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }
}
```

Then your caller would set `CallerContext.State` before calling the web service, and it would be available to both `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply`.  E.g.

```
...
try
{
    CallerContext.State = myId;

    ... call web service here ...
}
finally
{
    CallerContext.State = null;
}
```

and this will be available in `BeforeSendRequest`:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    var correlationState = CallerContext.State;

    ... do your stuff here

    return correlationState;
}
```

Note that use of try/finally to reset `CallerContext.State` to null isn't strictly necessary, but prevents unrelated code from accessing possibly sensitive data that you store there.

Comment: As you can see in my code sample I already do it. The issue is how to pass parameter to `BeforeSendRequest` method.

Comment: Another option I can use is to set parameter to message itself, but how can I access it in `request` parameter in `BeforeSendRequest`?

Answer (score 4):

I think simplest solution would be to put threadstatic variable in `LogMessageInspector`. Set the value in `BeforeSendRequest` and use it again in `AfterReceiveReply`.

I gets little bit more complex if you are using async operations, but all you would have to do is to pay closer attention to how you access and pass this local var.

MessageInspectors are intended to work on Message itself, so best solution would be to have something in the message to correlate to, e.g. requestId, OrderId, etc.

EDIT:

I would imagine service contract to look something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResponse Process( ServiceRequest request );
}


class ServiceRequest
{
    public Guid RequestID { get; set; }
    public string RequestData { get; set; }
}

class ServiceResponse
{
    public Guid RequestID { get; set; }
    public string ResponseData { get; set; }
}
```

RequestID would be generated on client side, and now you can do xpath on your messages and get RequestID to correlate request and response.

Comment: Could you please give me some sample on RequestID or OrderID. Couldn't find such properties.

Comment: Seems to be good but there is no opportunity to get `RequestID` in `BeforeSendRequest`